React Native Expo Mobile Display Issues (header cut off)
I'm making an app that has a header that uses an SVG and I'm having trouble with not getting my logo cut off on the mobile versions. This issue occurs on both the android emulator on my computer I'm using and on the mobile Expo Go app (Apple).
However, when I open the app on a website tab, it renders completely fine and isn't cut off.
Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix it? Here's the relevant code that renders the header.
LogoHeader.js:
import React from 'react';
import { Animated, StyleSheet, Image, View } from 'react-native';
import LogoSVG from '../assets/images/stanfoodlogo.svg';

const LogoHeader = ({ scrollY }) => {
  const headerHeight = scrollY.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 100],
    outputRange: [150, 90],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  });

  const headerOpacity = scrollY.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 70],
    outputRange: [1, 0],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  });

  return (
    <Animated.View style={[styles.header, { height: headerHeight, opacity: headerOpacity }]}>
      <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
        <LogoSVG style={styles.logoImage} />
      </View>
    </Animated.View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    width: '100%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#A4E67E',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    zIndex: 1000,
  },
  logoContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: '100%',
  },
  logoImage: {
    width: 300, 
    height: 100,
  },
});

export default LogoHeader;

index.js (entrypoint):
// import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, View, Animated, Text } from 'react-native';
import LogoHeader from '../components/LogoHeader';
import BottomNavBar from '../components/BottomNavBar';

const App = () => {
  const scrollY = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <LogoHeader scrollY={scrollY} />
      <Animated.ScrollView
        style={styles.scrollView}
        onScroll={Animated.event(
          [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: scrollY } } }],
          { useNativeDriver: false }
        )}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
      >
        {/* Main content goes here */}
        <View style={styles.content}>
          <Text style={styles.contentText}>Welcome to the StanFood App!</Text>
          <Text style={styles.contentText}>1...</Text>
          <Text style={styles.contentText}>2...</Text>
          <Text style={styles.contentText}>3...</Text>
        </View>
      </Animated.ScrollView>
      <BottomNavBar />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  scrollView: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  content: {
    paddingTop: 150, // Match header height
  },
  contentText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    margin: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});

export default App;

I figured the bottom nav bar isn't too important to include since that's not where the issue is occurring.
Here's the images of the issue for reference:
Mobile-cutoff issue
Image of image not cut off on web render
Any ideas on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated!!
I have tried to add padding to see if the image was being rendered too high up, and it seems like only the originally non-cut off portion is being shifted down.
Also, I've tried to use a PNG instead of SVG and it renders perfectly, but I would really prefer an SVG.
I've also tried to resize the image to no avail.

Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-safe-area-context it gives you a top value to add to render in the "safe area" i.e. below notches etc
